# angular isolated scope url string passing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

HTML context

```
<div dataminislider={{p.dataPreview}} preview-pup></div>
```

`p.dataPreview` contains a string of URLs, the URLs themselves being separated by a comma: `http://www.example.com/uploads/example/3/7.jpg,http://www.example.com/uploads/example/3/8.jpg,http://www.example.com/uploads/example/3/9.jpg`

The directive:

```
obApp.directive('previewPup', ['$rootScope',function($rootScope){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            localData: "@dataminislider"
        },
        link: function(scope, el, attr){
            console.log(scope.localData);               
       }
    }
}]);
```

I'm hit with this syntax error:

```
Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

If the content of `p.dataPreview` is say: 'abcd', the error goes away.
What's happening and how can i get around this?

Comment: maybe you should use quotes: `<div dataminislider="{{p.dataPreview}}" preview-pup></div>`

Comment: @Michael i've tried, same error

Comment: did you wrap the url string as well? I can't find any problem in the code you showed. See [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JF5peXbgvmmzQpwbnziM?p=preview). the problem is in your other code.

Comment: @Michael that's quite odd, as the url string are not wrapped in anything. Just plain strings i grab from the DB. I'll investigate further. Thank you.

Comment: As I said the bug is somewhere in your other code. Can't help you without more information/code snippets.

Comment: @Michael Turns out it's something wrong with that string. Problem is it's coming from a DB, packed with other properties in a JSON. All the other properties i can pass/watch fine, except for this one.

Comment: Maybe you should check that JSON for syntax errors or the expected dataPteview is not a string, but an array of strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div preview-pup dataminislider="p.dataPreview"></div>
```

`p.dataPreview` is the scope variable in controller and this `p.datapreview` holds the url r8
in directive use

```
scope:{
            localData: "=dataminislider"
        },
```

Comment: Same thing as "@" with {{}}. Error persists. Faulty string most likely.

Comment: p.dataPreview is it json response?. then check with placing some duumy data in p.dataPreview .. i think its with json format because i have complied same code what u have given with some text in p.dataPreview its working fine

Comment: It comes from a DB. I'll check and see. It's weird as heck.

Comment: I'll mark this as accepted, however there was no error with the JSON. Apparently the string in the DB, had an issue. I heve no idea what that issue was though, resolved it by repopulating those fields.